# Virtualbox second monitor only in scale mode (VM: Kali)

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, kali-linux

I run a Kali VM (2019.4) inside VirtualBox (6.1) 
In VM Settings I set number of monitors to 2 and boosted up the video memory to 128 mb.

Guest additions are installed within Kali.

When I boot, I only get a single display, kali doesn't recognise the second monitor and in VirtualBox's "View" when I click on "enable" on the second monitor it just rescales my window-size...

The weird thing is: when I select Scale Mode (Host+C) while the VM is booting, the second monitor appears (it's then also available in kalis display settings). But as soon as I go back to normal or fullscreen mode the second monitor disappears again.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. After Kali upgrade I can only see 1 monitor. Tried updating VirtualBox Additions but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I updated my VirtualBox to latest, as well as Extension Pack.
2. apt upgrade in Kali
3. copied VBoxLinuxAdditions.run (from Guest Additions CD) and ran it.
4. rebooted Kali

I now have two monitors again.

Comment: I did the exact same thing before writing this post, and it didn't work. 
Seems the new Update (either Kali or VirtualBox) fixes this now.